# Setting Xdebug - setting not respected

Tags: php, xdebug

I have MAMP successfully installed and have modified the mamp/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini file to include xdebug

however the remote_enable setting is OFF according to phpInfo 
What am I missing or doing wrong?

I do not have any other versions of php installed and verified the file I edited was the correct one by renaming it and restarting mamp.  Doing so disabled xdebug.

Please help.

Comment: Have you installed the php5-xdebug package? What's the output of `php5 -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set it in your php.ini file. Here's how I set mine. Try this [link](http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2011/08/xdebug-cachegrind-and-mamp-on-mac-osx/)

```
[xdebug]

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.renite_enable = 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = '/var/log'
```

Answer (score 0):

MAMP seems to have an interesting setup for the php.ini files. Instead of trying to edit the file directly, use MAMP in the menu bar go to `File > Edit Template > PHP > PHP 5.6.2 php.ini` and add your settings there.

When I compare `mamp/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini` to the file that opens through MAMP, they are different.

Updating the MAMP file instead of going directly to the logical file it should be will apply the changes once you stop/start MAMP.